# Python: Formatting a string using variable names placeholders

Tags: python, string-formatting, iterable-unpacking

Consider the following string building statement:

```
s="svn cp %s/%s/ %s/%s/" % (root_dir, trunk, root_dir, tag)
```

Using four `%s` can be confusing, so I prefer using variable names:

```
s="svn cp {root_dir}/{trunk}/ {root_dir}/{tag}/".format(**SOME_DICTIONARY)
```

When `root_dir`, `tag` and `trunk` are defined within the scope of a class, using `self.__dict__` works well:

```
s="svn cp {root_dir}/{trunk}/ {root_dir}/{tag}/".format(**self.__dict__)
```

But when the variables are local, they are not defined in a dictionary, so I use string concatenation instead:

```
s="svn cp "+root_dir+"/"+trunk+"/ "+root_dir+"/"+tag+"/"
```

I find this method quite confusing, but I don't know any way to construct a string using in-line local variables.

**How can I construct the string using variable names when the variables are local?**

**Update**: Using the [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) function did the trick.

Note that mixing local and object variables is allowed! e.g.,

```
s="svn cp {self.root_dir}/{trunk}/ {self.root_dir}/{tag}/".format(**locals())
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) function

```
s="svn cp {root_dir}/{trunk}/{root_dir}/{tag}/".format(**locals())
```

**EDIT:**

Since python 3.6 you can use [string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
s = f"svn cp {root_dir}/{trunk}/{root_dir}/{tag}/"
```

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot `locals()`.

Comment: note that '{a}'.format(**locals()), '{a}'.format(a=a) and '{0}'.format(a) are timed at 450ns, 410 and 215 respectivelly. (ok it's ns...)

Comment: note string interpolation (which is pretty awesome and works for the vast majority of use cases) will format immediately; in some cases (like template string arguments), you might want to call the `format` method at a later time, after initial string assignment

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `s="svn cp {root_dir}/{trunk}/ {root_dir}/{tag}/".format(**locals())` ?

Answer (score 0):

less cryptic and faster

```py
"my name is {__name__}".format_map(locals())
```

> [str.format_map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map)(mapping)
>
> Similar to str.format(**mapping), except that mapping is used directly and not copied to a dict.